# Python Socket Class transfer functions for any networking related program

Tags: python, performance, socket

This code is meant to send an object (any object) over a connection to a recieving program. I want to make sure that i haven't made any red flags. It seems to work fine, i've sent tuples with data (bools, strings and lists with other lists) and it gets recieved fine.

```
import pickle

packetsize = 4096

def send_msg(conn, data):
    try:
        msg = pickle.dumps(data)
        print("calcing packetcount")
        packetcount = str(int(len(msg)/(packetsize))+1)
        if (len(msg)%packetsize) == 0: packetcount -= 1
        while len(packetcount) != 8:
            packetcount = "0" + packetcount
        print("sending packetcount: " + packetcount)
        conn.sendall(packetcount.encode())
        print("sending message")
        conn.sendall(msg)
        print("sent message")
        return True
    except:
        return False

def recv_msg(conn):
    # Read message length and unpack it into an integer
    print("waiting for message")
    messagesize = int(conn.recv(8).decode())
    print("got message size: {} packets".format(str(messagesize)))
    print("recieving message")
    data = []
    for _ in range(messagesize):
        print("recieving packet")
        packet = conn.recv(packetsize)
        print("recieved packet: {}".format(packet))
        if not packet: break
        data.append(packet)
    # Read the message data
    print("got ALL PACKETS")
    return pickle.loads(b"".join(data))
```

Comment: Please show all of your imports and your entry point

Comment: The first *red flag* is the Pickle module itself. From module doc: *Warning:
 The pickle module is not secure. Only unpickle data you trust. It is possible to construct malicious pickle data which will execute arbitrary code during unpickling. Never unpickle data that could have come from an untrusted source, or that could have been tampered with.*. Depending on your expected use case, it may be blocking (if untrusted data is expected) or irrelevant (in a fully controlled environment).

Comment: @Reinderien, this is supposed to be imported as functions from another file (there are no other imports), this is also going to be called as a function on a application-to-application system (no leaving localhost).

Answer (score 1):

> this is also going to be called as a function on a application-to-application system (no leaving localhost).

Then don't use TCP/IP sockets at all; use [Unix domain sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.AF_UNIX) or some other host-only pipe-based IPC. Maybe (though it's doubtful) you actually did use `AF_UNIX`, but since you haven't shown your connection instantiation code that's anyone's best guess.

If your existing code works, that's only by accident. You've stumbled into the trap that all beginners encounter in IP sockets: assumption of non-fragmentation. The idea of a packet count is entirely meaningless at the application level, and you cannot assume the length or count of any packets. Your protocol needs to be packet-agnostic and instead define a message in terms of its total byte length.